# change sender email address of share wishlist mail in magento

Tags: php, magento

i want to change the sender email address of the share wishlist email a customer send when share his wishlist with a friend, i'm trying to put the custmer email as the sender address, and the customer name as the from name, thought it could be done in the admin, you just can change it to another one, but i want the customer email, need some help here

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing the code a bit, it would seem that this email is send from

```
app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
```

So you need to overwrite this controller. I have never done such a thing, but it is doable. There is a topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266066/overwriting-overloading-a-controller-class-in-magento) and if you google 'magento override controller' you'll also find a lot off info.

After that you must re-implement (meaning copy and edit) the method `sendAction()`. In it is a call

```
$emailModel->sendTransactional();
```

I also think you should leave the sender address to that of the store, because 
setting it to another address might mark the message as spam. But if you want to
do it just change the second parameter of this call to an array with keys 'name' 
and 'email' and the desired values.

But I strongly advise to set the Reply-To header too. That is possible because this model uses a Zend_Mail object to do the dirty work and treats this object as a singleton. Meaning that if you create it as first and configure it, the next mail will be sent with this configuration. In code, change

```
foreach($emails as $email) {
    $emailModel->sendTransactional(
        Mage::getStoreConfig('wishlist/email/email_template'),
//snip
```

to

```
foreach($emails as $email) {
    $mail = $emailModel->getMail();
    $mail->setReplyTo($customer->getEmail());
    $emailModel->sendTransactional(
        Mage::getStoreConfig('wishlist/email/email_template'),
//snip
```

Success

Comment: thank you, i will keep in mind your recommendation, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I would not do it that way. Instead I would set the from address to be that of my web store and set the `Reply-To` header to be that of the recipients friend. Spoofing from addresses like that can land your email in spam traps.

Comment: i even don't know how to change the replay-to, that is what i'm trying to find out, but i don't think changing the from address can be a bad way, actually, this is what i'm trying to do, any idea how to do it, thanks anyway