# change sender email address of share wishlist mail in magento 1.8

Tags: php, magento

Change the sender email address of the share wishlist email a customer send when share his wishlist with a friend, i'm trying to put the custmer email as the sender address, and the customer name as the from name, thought it could be done in the admin, you just can change it to another one, but i want the customer email, need some help here

Comment: possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342736/change-sender-email-address-of-share-wishlist-mail-in-magento

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change sender email address of share wishlist mail in magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342736/change-sender-email-address-of-share-wishlist-mail-in-magento)

Comment: You are not working